# Вывод тех данных в профиле, которые ввел пользователь

Tags: php, html, sql

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы выводились в профиле только те данные, которые пользователь ввел? Если пользователь ввел `email`, то поле `email:xxx@m.com` показывалось, если нет, то все поле скрывалось и шло другое. Киньте, пожалуйста, пример если можете, или туториал чтобы хотя бы понят пример работы. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// $result - массив, полученный от mysql_fetch_array();
if($result['email'] !== ""){ // если email записан
 // выводим его
 echo "email - ".$result['email'];
}
```

Comment: Исправьте **$result['email'] != ""**

Comment: Да. Спасибо:) Исправил.